# Bash/ Delete files by find expcept 3 files

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have the next command to delete files which are large than 100KB:

```
find . -size +100k -delete
```

I want that it doesn't delete 3 files: `a.html b.txt` and `c.html`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should make it:

```
find . -size +100k ! -name "a.html" ! -name "b.html" ! -name "c.html" -delete
```

Comment: Say what? He wants to remove all files, _but_ those mentioned, that matches the critera of being bigger than 100k.

Comment: Uhms true, I didn't understand it properly. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
find . -size +100k ! -regex "^\./[abc]\.html$" -delete
```

Add `-maxdepth 1` is you want to perform deletion in current directory only.

Comment: `[abc].*\.html` seems a bit dangerous, especially for people who don't know regular expressions. `a_very_important_file.html` would get deleted too.

Comment: @Jite Actually we are excluding these files from deletion. Regex can be made more restrictive as per the requirements.

Comment: Hehe, yes of course, my bad. In this case it's not _that_ bad _not_ to delete it, but the fact remains that your example doesn't only keep `a.html` but any file starting with an `a` and ends with `.html` with any number of characters in between.

Comment: @Jite: Corrected the regex in answer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Also, I think ^ and $ are implied in the "whole path" regex matching supported by find i.e. `\./[abc]\.html` should suffice.

Comment: @svante: It's more or less never a bad idea to include it as a best practice, so I'd recommend re-adding it for the sake of education. Nice comment-steal btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-command-exclude-ignore-files/

At the end, they say this:

*Find all .dot files but ignore .htaccess file:*

```
$ find . -type f \( -iname ".*" ! -iname ".htaccess" \)
```

This should do the trick for you, just substitude the -iname ".htaccess" for the name of your files :)

Hope it helps!